# Understanding @(posedge) in Verilog

Tags: verilog

In the circuit below, I'm trying to count the number of clock pulses that happen while the `decode` signal is high. In order to do this, I create a `composite` wire that takes the AND of `clk` and `decode`, and increment a counter at the positive edges of this signal.

```
module countPulses(clk, decode);
  input clk;
  input decode;

  wire composite = clk & decode;
  
  reg  [15:0] composite_counter = 16'h0000;  // Increments too often
  reg  [15:0] delayed_counter   = 16'h0000;  // Lags 1 cycle behind desired
  reg  [15:0] desired           = 16'h0001;  // Intended counter behavior

  always @(posedge composite)
  begin
    composite_counter <= composite_counter + 1;
    desired <= desired + 1;
  end

  // Manually fix up the desired results on the falling edge of `decode`
  always @(negedge decode)
    desired <= desired - 1;

  always @(posedge clk)
    if (decode) delayed_counter <= delayed_counter + 1;

endmodule
```

Unfortunately, `composite_counter` doesn't work as I expected. I'm looking for the values shown in `desired`, but instead, `composite_counter` increments *again* at the falling edge of the `decode` signal. I don't understand why this happens, as you can see in the trace that when this occurs, `composite` and `decode` are both zero. There should be no overlap between the rising edge of `clk` and the falling edge of `decode`, but for some reason, it's being treated as a `posedge` anyways. I'm new to Verilog and hardware design, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding how `@ posedge` works.

I also tried incrementing a counter (`delayed_counter`) at `posedge clk` instead of `posedge composite` and checking if `decode` is high. This doesn't exhibit the double-counting behavior that `composite_counter` does, but the values are delayed one cycle from those in `desired`. I understand why this is happening, but wanted to point it out as a potential solution that *won't* work.

[image: GtkWave traces showing undesired behavior]

With that, my two questions are:

1. Why does `always @(posedge composite)` fire when `composite` is (and remains) zero?
2. How can I achieve the behavior shown by `desired` without resorting to such haphazard techniques as decrementing the counter on the falling edge of the `decode` signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition between the falling edge of `decode` and the rising edge of `clock`.

Zoom in your wave viewer and you’ll probably see `composite` going high very briefly at that edge.

To fix it, make sure that `decode` goes low some nonzero time before `clock` goes high. Or, even better, instead of using a gated clock (google this term if you don’t know it), use `decode` as an enable signal, and `clock` as a clock.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about this, but when I said "There should be no overlap" I meant that I stepped through at the timescale of the simulation and confirmed that there was no overlap. At the 1500ns mark, `decode` instantly becomes 0, and `clk` instantly becomes 1, so `composite` never goes high. Unless the race condition happens within iVerilog itself?

As for using `decode` as an enable signal and `clk` as a clock, isn't that the approach I took with `delayed_counter`?

Comment: @ecaostone yes, `delayed_counter` uses the correct approach. The only reason that counter is delayed is because, again, you have a race condition when `decode` initially goes high. Fix your race conditions and your design will be much better behaved.

Comment: `decode` and `clk` are both produced outside of my design, but I'll investigate them a bit more and (hopefully) mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: If this is fpga work, you can likely use clock manage mental resources to delay the clock signal by a fraction of a period where it enters the chip. Or use its negative edge instead of positive within your design.

Comment: Oddly enough, this design will only ever run in a simulator, so while the usual hardware constraints don't apply, clever tricks like that aren't an option.

Comment: Then you can delay a signal with a simple `#5` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The `delayed_counter` is the normal way I used to count when `decode` is high.

In your waveform, `delayed_counter` increments at 1500ns, this really means that `clk` edge "sees" a high `decode`. This can explain why `composite_counter` increments again at that time: there's a glitch on `composite`. You're doing functional simulation with zero delay, so we are hardly to tell the order of 2 events if they happen at the exactly same time. Even though the edge of `clk` and `decode` aligns, the internal event scheduler of your simulater places the event of "`decode` rises" before the event of "`clk` rises". There's something to do with the way you produce these 2 signals in your testbench.